# Want to run PHP query when submit button submitted using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I want to run insert.php query if button name with **"addUser"** is submitted i don't know how to pass **addUser** name parameter using AJAX to insert.php file where it check if button is submitted or not .
**if i remove** if statement in `insert.php` file this is inserting users to database but if directly visit `insert.php` its inserting empty records in table
i want to prevent entry of empty records in table if i visit insert.php directly .

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" id="addForm">
Username :<input type="text" name="username" id="userName" />
Passkey :<input type="password" name="passkey" id="passKey"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="addUser" id="submitBtn" value="Inser New User"/>
</form>

<script>
    $("#addForm").submit(function(e){
        let userNameZ = $("#userName").val();
        let passKeyZ = $("#passKey").val();

          $.ajax({
            url:'insert.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {userName:userNameZ,passKey:passKeyZ},
            success: function(resp) {
               if(resp == "inserted") {
                   $("#addForm").trigger("reset");
                    alert("New user inserted");
               } else {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
               }
            }
         });
    });
</script>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php 
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
if(isset($_POST['addUser'])){
    $userName = trim($_POST['userName']);
    $passKey = trim($_POST['passKey']);
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username,passkey) VALUES (:userName,:passKey)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(':userName'=>$userName, ':passKey'=>$passKey));

    if($stmt) {
        echo "inserted";
    } else {
        echo "not inserted";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: just change this `if(isset($_POST['addUser'])){` to `if(!empty($_POST['userName']) &&  !empty($_POST['passKey']))`

Comment: what if i have more than 10 values to be submit ?

Comment: on that case, you'll have to set one variable that is required and that's the one you will only check. or just `if(!empty($_POST))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `if(isset($_POST['addUser'])){`
to 
`if(isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['passKey'])){`

OR in ajax, change

`data: {userName:userNameZ,passKey:passKeyZ,addUser:1},`
**Notice:** `,addUser:1`

Adding answer to your comment

> what if i have more than 10 values to be submit

.

You can use `$("#addForm").serialize()` and pass directly to data. Like
`data: $("#addForm").serialize(),`

Comment: what if have more than 1 form in same page ?

Comment: all posting to insert.php ? @DoeJohn

Comment: i want to execute php query when particular forms button is submmited

Comment: i want to group multiple php query files as 1 file . But i want execute multi-forms from same script

Comment: @DoeJohn you want all forms to be posted in single post request ?

Comment: i want to create different queries in 1 php file . i want execute particular query when some particular button is submitted

Comment: It seems your Original Question has been solved. Please ask a new question with detailed description. Accept this answer if it has helped you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173038/discussion-between-doe-john-and-jigar).